# find the different and the power of values between 2 columns in sql database

Tags: sql

i just work in new project and i need to make some mathematics operation and compare between 2 columns in my database , in my database i have 2 tables (before_process) and (after_process)both of them they have on column name (doc_num), this doc_num in (before_process table have some values ), but when it processing the values will be different :

my code :

```
SELECT befor_process.SYS_ID,
  befor_process.st_id,
  after_prcoess.file_name,
  after_prcoess.FORM,
  COUNT(*)             AS DB_ST,
  COUNT(befor_process.doc_num) AS DB_ZS
FROM log_table after_prcoess
INNER JOIN status_table befor_process
ON after_prcoess.doc_num       = befor_process.doc_num
WHERE after_prcoess.FORM          IS NOT NULL
AND befor_process.STATUS  = 100
AND after_prcoess.doc_num NOT IN
  ( SELECT doc_num FROM status_table WHERE STATUS >= 101
  )
GROUP BY befor_process.SYS_ID,
  befor_process.st_id,
  after_prcoess.file_name,
  after_prcoess.FORM
ORDER BY befor_process.SYS_ID,
  befor_process.st_id;
```

and my query_result will be :

[image]

but what result desired is (if the 2 values equal or the double than in the after_process table the value will be null , But if more than double it will give the result , like below picture :

[image]

Comment: Please don't tag multiple conflicting RDBMS. Only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. I have removed all the conflicting tags, please retag the correct RDBMS and **only** the correct RDBMS. Thanks.

Comment: `COUNT(befor_process.doc_num) ` can never be greater than `COUNT(*)`.  Are you sure the query and results correspond to each other?

Answer (score 0):

Add this column in the select list:

```
CASE WHEN COUNT(befor_process.doc_num) / COUNT(*) NOT IN (1, 2) THEN COUNT(befor_process.doc_num) - 2 * COUNT(*) END Result
```

If you use a database like SQL Server that performs integer division between integers then multiply also by `1.0` the result of the division:

```
CASE WHEN 1.0 * COUNT(befor_process.doc_num) / COUNT(*) NOT IN (1, 2) THEN COUNT(befor_process.doc_num) - 2 * COUNT(*) END Result
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic you want is expressed as:

```
(case when COUNT(*) > 2 * COUNT(befor_process.doc_num) 
      then 2 * COUNT(befor_process.doc_num) - COUNT(*)
 end) as result
```

My only confusion is that `COUNT(befor_process.doc_num)` can never be greater than `COUNT(*)`, but you question implies that this is so.  Perhaps the column aliases are backwards in the question.